# How to get BlockReference's boxmin in eyeshot

Tags: eyeshot

I add some entity into a block,and add reference into viewport.
I coded "new blockReference(blockName).boxmin" ,
and it will catch exception "NullReferenceException".
what else code i need to add?
Or it have another way to get group entity boxsize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a `new blockReference(blockName).BoxMin` wont have the block regenerated.
Get the block that is already inserted in the viewport and check that object bounding box.

Let's say the blockname is "Block1" you could do :

```
var br = viewportLayout1.Entities.OfType<BlockReference>()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(b => b.BlockName == "Block1");

if(br != null)
{
    var boxMin = br.BoxMin;
    var boxMax = br.BoxMax;
}
```

The reason behind why you need the block in the `ViewportLayout` is that `BoxMin` and `BoxMax` are align to world axis so position in the world is necessary to know in order to compute the box. If you rotate or translate the `BlockReference` the `BoxMin` and `BoxMax` will be different.